# I have been searching for the title of this book, please help

Tags: story-identification

So in this book a man crashes his ship on a new planet. The ship is overgrown with plants before the man can repair it leaving him stranded. I didn’t read this book my dad did and he would never told me the answer and now he can’t. If anyone knows the name that would be amazing.

Comment: Help us help you, take a look at this [checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and try to add as many details as you can!

Comment: Crash-landed on a jungle planet isn't enough to go on.